# C++ Manager Data Fields

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a manager class in C++, or at least collection of globally available data fields. I simply want to be able to get and set some global data without the need of functions. I also want to avoid using Singletons if I can.

I've tried a static class:

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H

class Manager
{
public:
    static float AspectRatio;
};

#endif MANAGER_H
```

but I get LNK2001 compiler errors complaining of unresolved externals when I try to use "Manager::AspectRatio"

I've also tried global fields:

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H

float Manager_AspectRatio = 1.0f;

#endif MANAGER_H
```

but I get LNK2005 compiler errors complaining of multiple definitions when I include the "manager.h" in multiple files. I thought the point of using header guards was to prevent multiple definitions?

Any insight as to how I can create a set of global data fields that I can access and mutate throughout my program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've *declared* your fields fine. You just haven't told the compiler where to store them.

As the linker error suggests, you have to nominate *one* storage location, which means it can't be in the header.

Add a file **manager.cpp**:

```
#include "manager.h"
float Manager::AspectRatio = 1.0f; // for the static class member version
```

Answer (score 2):

in your `manager.cpp`

```
float Manager::AspectRatio = 1.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error messages you are getting, I believe, are linker errors and not compiler errors. The problem is that you have assigned AspectRatio as a *static* float. If you decide to do away with the static specifier, you can do:

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H 

class Manager
{
public:
    float AspectRatio;
};

int main () {
     Manager m;
     m.AspectRatio = 10;

}
```

Also, as an aside, avoid using #defines, since it is not the C++ way of programming.

Comment: This unfortunately does not make "m" globally accessible. I can only access its instance within the main function, which isn't what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a static member can't be inside a function.

```
class Manager
{
public:
    float AspectRatio;
};

float Manager::AspectRatio = 1.0f;
int main () {
   std::cout << Manager::AspectRation << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```